# How do I quit from vi?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, editors

I'm new to `vi`. I started `vi` on my Ubuntu machine and I can't quit. I see the editor and I can write text, at the bottom line there is a label "recording".

How do I quit the `vi` editor?

Comment: The "recording" by the way meant that you were recording a macro. Not that that matters any more.

Comment: For those who haven't seen that joke yet: https://twitter.com/iamdevloper/statuses/435555976687923200

Comment: [Stack Overflow: Helping One Million Developers Exit Vim](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/23/stack-overflow-helping-one-million-developers-exit-vim/), [How to exit the Vim editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11828270/995714), [How to exit help in vim](https://superuser.com/q/663006/241386)

Comment: vim Cheat Sheet: https://vim.rtorr.com/

Answer (score 102, accepted):

[vim is a modal editor](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_02.html#02.2). Hit the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key to get into *Normal* (command) mode then type <kbd>:q</kbd> and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

To quit without saving any changes, type <kbd>:q!</kbd> and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

See also [Getting out](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_02.html#02.7) in Vim documentation.

Comment: Thanks: I tried that commands, but after running them I was prompted with: `E37: No write since last change (add ! to override)`. I have nothing to save.

Comment: Use `:wq` if you want to save what you have edited and then exit.  `:q!` if you want to exit and leave your changes behind.

Comment: Or if you've written something you want to make a copy of, `:w newFileName.txt`, then sort out the read-only issue outside of **vi** or **vim**.

Comment: quit `:q` ; force quit `:q!` ; quit and save `:wq` or `:x`

Comment: @Jonas, next time try `:qall!`, I suspect you have open more files within one single buffer.

Answer (score 13):

I use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> to generate the <kbd>esc</kbd> sequence, this keeps me from having to move my fingers from the home row (remember the <kbd>esc</kbd> key was in a different place when `vi` was invented. `:wq` will write all files regardeless of necessity. I suggest using `ZZ` (which is <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> twice) which will only write if a change has been made in the file. Also `:xa` is the same as `ZZ` except if you have more than 1 file open in the editor instance (such as vim tabs). *note: I'm not sure all this is 100% compat with all vi clones, but I know it works with vim*

Comment: Thanks. The `ZZ` command seems to be useful. I can see the point with `Ctrl+[` but I'm using a swedish keyboard layout and I have to press `AltGr+8` to get `[` so that would be `Ctrl+AltGr+8` for me :(

Comment: Also note `ZQ` is effectively the same as `:q!`.  However, this is not standard.  `ZZ`, on the other hand, *is* [specified in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/vi.html).

Answer (score 4):

The quit from the vi is another way is
<kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>:x</kbd>.

The option is used for save and quit at the
same time.

Comment: Note that like `ZZ`, `:x` will write the file only if its content has changed, unlike `:wq`.

Answer (score 2):

As Sinan said, vim is a modal editor. If you want to know whether that works for you you should maybe invest some time and run `vimtutor` which is an interactive way to learn vim. (It also covers how to exit, what the modes mean and what you can do in each mode).

Answer (score -2):

After modification, please press <kbd>ESC</kbd> and the given command `:wq!`.

This will forcefully write the new modification on the read-only file. Earlier it was not working because the file is read-only.

Comment: Why are you answering a question from 4 years ago, with basically a rehash of the top answer?

It's wrong anyway: this won't force write a read-only file- it will try to write, might fail, and then will force quit without saving.

Comment: I tried with the previous comments and it was not working. I thought it would be useful to share what I have done. It is not important when the question was posted, but whether the solutions are applicable or not.

Answer (score -3):

try combination of <kbd>control</kbd> and <kbd>Z</kbd>

Comment: This will keep vi in background;