# Spoofing or removing DHCP client hostname in response to DHCP server

Tags: linux, dhcp, hostname

In linux, when my machine requests an IP address it also sends the hostname back to the DHCP server. How can I stop my machine from sending back this hostname?

I use `dhclient`, possibly via NetworkManager.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find host-name in dhcp client configuration to remove or add hostname.

For example:

Debian / Ubuntu Linux - `/etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf`

```
$ sudo vi /etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf
```

Set hostname as you need on the following line:
    send host-name "yourhostname";

RHEL / [Fedora](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/System_Administrators_Guide/s1-networkscripts-interfaces.html) / [CentOS](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-networkscripts-interfaces.html#s2-networkscripts-interfaces-eth0) Linux - `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` (for 1st DHCP network interface)

Open configuration file, enter:

```
# vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
```

Append hostname as you need on the following line :

```
DHCP_HOSTNAME=yourhostname
```

It is also possible for NetworkManager [to send the hostname](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager#Hostname_problems); see `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` looking for:

```
[keyfile]
hostname=your_hostname
```

Comment: As a side note, I find it funny that you gave specific instructions to use **vi** to edit those files instead of just saying they have to be edited and letting the readers decide how to do it. Maybe they prefer **nano**. Suggesting **vi** can lead to questions like ["How do I quit from Vi?"](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3334/1174) :-)

Comment: vi came naturally :) but I agreed.. instructions could have been explained better.